# Override AllAuth Views and Pass context data to templates

Tags: django-views, django-templates, django-allauth

I am not sure if i am titling this correctly, however i have a standard base.html file that includes block content from overridden allauth templates, mainly account/email.html, account/password_change.html, account/password_set.html and socialaccount/connections.html.  each of these feed into base.html depending on tab selected.  the tabs correspond to the default allauth views, accounts/email, accounts/password/change, accounts/password/set, and accounts/social/connections.

When i load base.html, I am able to grab the user profile information from a custom Profile model

```
@login_required
def base(request):
    email = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(my_user=email)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'profile': profile})
```

as long as i am on the base.html template view, the username displays in the upper right of the screen, and i have access to all profile information for use in the template.  however, when i click onto an allauth default view, that still extends base.html, the username information in the header disappears and profile data is no longer available until i click back on the main base.html view.

Can someone help me with what i am missing on how to maintain the username in the upper right of the screen always in the base.html file (even as views change), as well as access to profile information across the different views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone else overriding AllAuth Views, was able to solve via:

```
class MyEmailView(EmailView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        email = self.request.user
        profile_data = Profile.objects.filter(my_user=email)
        context = super(MyEmailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["profile_data"] = profile_data
        print(context["profile_data"])
        return context
```

urls.py

```
# override of email view to add user profile context data
    path("accounts/email/", MyEmailView.as_view(), name="account_email"),
```